# ListView with an array

Tags: android, listview

I want to fill a ListView without an array of all the same things.

I have a class "TijdsregistratieKaart"  with these strings, boolean & double.

```
public class TijdsregistratieKaart {
  public String date,customerName,description,startTime,stopTime,taskDocumentNo_,activity,project,internalInformation,externalInformation;
  public Boolean coaching;
  public double percentageComplete;
  ...
}
```

now my question is how to i put all these things in a listview.
so that Date is in a different cell than customerName & description,... I can't find an example of a listview without using an array of all the same strings or double's or...

At the moment i got an TijdsregistratieKaartAdapter class en fill my listView like this:

```
private class tijdsregistratieKaartAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TijdsregistratieKaart> {

    private ArrayList<TijdsregistratieKaart> items;

    public tijdsregistratieKaartAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<TijdsregistratieKaart> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.tijdsregistratiekaartrij, null);
        }
        TijdsregistratieKaart tijdsregistratiekaart = items.get(position);
        if (tijdsregistratiekaart != null) {
            TextView at = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TRKtxtDatum);
            TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TRKtxtKlantNaam);
            TextView ct = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TRKtxtDescription);
            TextView dt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TRKtxtTaskDocNo);
            TextView et = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TRKtxtActivity);
            TextView ft = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TRKtxtCoaching);
            TextView gt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TRKtxtExternalInformation);
            TextView ht = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TRKtxtInternalInformation);
            TextView it = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TRKtxtPercentageComplete);
            TextView jt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TRKtxtProject);
            TextView kt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TRKtxtStartTime);
            TextView lt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TRKtxtStopTime);
            if (at != null) {
                at.setText("Datum:\n" + tijdsregistratiekaart.date);
            }
            if (bt != null) {
                bt.setText("Klant naam:\n " + tijdsregistratiekaart.customerName);
            }
            if (ct != null) {
                ct.setText("Omschrijving:\n " + tijdsregistratiekaart.description);
            }
            if (dt != null) {
                dt.setText("Document Nr:\n" + tijdsregistratiekaart.taskDocumentNo_);
            }
            if (et != null) {
                et.setText("Activiteit:\n " + tijdsregistratiekaart.activity);
            }
            if (ft != null) {
                ft.setText("Begeleiding:\n " + tijdsregistratiekaart.coaching);
            }
            if (gt != null) {
                gt.setText("Externe Informatie:\n" + tijdsregistratiekaart.externalInformation);
            }
            if (ht != null) {
                ht.setText("Interne Informatie:\n " + tijdsregistratiekaart.internalInformation);
            }
            if (it != null) {
                it.setText("% Afgewerkt:\n " + tijdsregistratiekaart.percentageComplete);
            }
            if (jt != null) {
                jt.setText("Project:\n" + tijdsregistratiekaart.project);
            }
            if (kt != null) {
                kt.setText("Start uur:\n " + tijdsregistratiekaart.startTime);
            }
            if (lt != null) {
                lt.setText("Stop uur:\n " + tijdsregistratiekaart.stopTime);
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

but if i do it like this. it is 1 big cell with different items. and i want a different cell for each items so i can add onclickItemListeners on the ones that need one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, No need to use ListView, I'm going to use a scrollView and then add textView inside it. this is going to be a lot easier & the same result.
example: http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/02/android-scrollview.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider re-designing your flow. I know it is not really what you want to hear. But that would be a pain to have to scroll up and down and side to side to see all my information.

Instead, you could show the user the important data in the `ListView`. And then have a feature where they can click on an item and see more details regarding the item. Then you can have your `onClickListeners` in the more detailed view or in some other manner.